# Compiled with problems: ERROR in ./src/App.js 13:37-43 export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 13:37-43

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Answer (score 4):

You probably installed `react-router-dom` v6 and followed a tutorial that uses v5. In v5, `Switch` has been replaced by `Routes`. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

// Use `<Routes>` instead of `<Switch>`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
  <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
  <Link to='/about'>About</Link>

  <Routes>
    <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

This will Solve your Error;